# Generate Link/URL preview in HTML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, meta-tags

What do I need to generate a link preview? e.g., when you post a link on facebook or whatsapp, the link gets posted with a small thumbnail and some introductory text. I want to achieve something similar. E.g. I want to post a link to a news article.. or a news website news.bbc.co.uk.
I know they have META tags which have things like: short description, image thumbnail (link to), title etc, somewhere in the HEAD /HEAD. Lets say I want to put the 'pure' HTML code in a div called "DIV_3". Right now I am just trying to get the entire URL/website into a string (I'm guessin this will be extremely long), so I can maybe parse it for the META tags.
So here is what I tried:

1. I tried using simple Javascript and AJAX and PHP:
   Javascript is:

```
    AJAX.onreadystatechange = function()
    {   if((AJAX.readyState == 4) && (AJAX.status == 200))
            {   var PHP_REPLY = AJAX.responseText; 
                document.getElementById("DIV_3").innerHTML = PHP_REPLY;
    }       }
    var URL = document.getElementById("INPUT_url").value;   
    AJAX.open("POST", "PHP_FILE_GET_CONTENTS.PHP", true);
    var PARAM = "URL=" + URL; 
    AJAX.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    AJAX.send(PARAM);
```

The PHP is (PHP_FILE_GET_CONTENTS.PHP) ::

```
    <?PHP
    if (isset($_POST['URL']))
    {   $URL = $_POST['URL'];   
        $URL_STRING = file_get_contents($URL);
        echo $URL_STRING;   }
   echo " POST URL IS ::|||" . $_POST['URL'] . " |||:: <BR><BR>";               
   ?>
```

The response that ends up in DIV_3 is something like this:
""Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
.. I am using WAMP server.
The broader question is, what should I use? normal AJAX? not working, JQUERY AJAX? I bet these arent that different? I read somewhere that I need to use NODE JS? How to I set about extracting the meta tags of a website so I can generate a proper link/URL preview. There are some question that discuss using JQUERY and parsing the returned string, but some clearly say something like NODE.JS has to be used.
Could someone please guide me as to where to start?
Thanks, all guidance appreciated..

p.s.: the URL/Link will be provided by a user on the webpate on a simple text input which has an ID of "INPUT_url"

Comment: UPDATE:: I was able to finally use file_get_contents() in PHP. My PHP version and Apache weren't compatible.